# If I am observing a collection via KVO, am I notified of changes to objects within the collection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, key-value-observing

I assume not, but always like to double check.

Let's say I have an NSMutableArray I'm KVObserving. It holds a bunch of Employee object. If I fully assign the array, then no doubt I'll observe the change. However, what if I change one of the Employee objects references/value/objects in the array, such as employee.salary.

I assume there is no KVO notification, here correct?

And if you ever wanted something like this, how would it be achieved?

Comment: Isn't that what `addObserver:toObjectsAtIndexes:forKeyPath:options:context` is for? But of course since the array itself is mutable, maintaining that is going to be a formidable proposition.

Answer (score 1):

One quick nitpick: you can't be key-value observing an `NSMutableArray`. That's not what KVO does. What you're doing is key-value observing some property (say "employees") of some object. That property may be typed as an `NSMutableArray` (although that's a terrible idea) or merely backed by an `NSMutableArray`. But you're not observing the array. You are observing the object for changes in its `employees` property.

Key-value observing a collection property does **not** observe the properties of the objects in the collection. In general, there's no way to observe all properties, wholesale, of any object.

If you want to observe some specific property or properties of the objects in a collection, you should:

1. Consolidate all mutations of that collection to separate methods. You should already have done this to make your `employees` property KVO-compliant. In particular, I recommend that you implement the indexed collection mutating accessors.
2. Within those methods, use `-addObserver:toObjectsAtIndexes:forKeyPath:options:context:` and `-removeObserver:fromObjectsAtIndexes:forKeyPath:context:` to start and stop observing some key path(s) of the elements that are being added to or removed from the collection. You need to do this in the setter (`-setEmployees:`) for the `employees` property, too (stop observing all of the elements of the old array, replace it with the new array, start observing all of the elements of the new array).
3. Don't forget to stop observing the elements before the array is released, for example in `-dealloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
[[employee mutableArrayValueForKey:@"salary"] addObject:...]
```